# Evolution of the human Y chromosome

Tags: genetics, evolution, adaptation

[This recent news article](https://www.msn.com/en-gb/health/medical/humans-could-become-extinct-unless-we-change-sex-as-we-know-it/ar-BB1iYe7z?ocid=msedgntp&pc=U531&cvid=b0a7ae8bfa4f47dcb87bd0ca2e5f3e9f&ei=71) suggests the number of genes in human male Y chromosome has steadily been reducing in the Y chromosome for a long time and is in danger of dying out all together.

What I want to know, is if this is a bad thing, why don't normal evolutionary forces act to prevent this? For example if some individual is born in the future with a further reduced gene count in their Y chromosome and this reduces or eliminates their fertility, they will will have less offspring and that trait will die out. Why would the human race evolve in a way that is disadvantages to reproduction, when that is the main driving force of evolution?

Answer (score 3):

> What I want to know, is if this is a bad thing, why don't normal evolutionary forces act to prevent this?

You seem to be attributing a moral value to an evolutionary process. So does the article you linked to your post (probably for sensationalism), which is not a scientific way of reasoning. I suggest you read the [original article instead](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-020-58997-2#Abs1). In the abstract, you can read :

> The results of our study suggest these forces are not exclusive to the Y chromosome, and chromosomal degeneration may have occurred throughout our evolutionary history. The reduction of recombination could additionally result in rapid fixation through isolation, of specialized functions resulting in a cost-benefit relationship during times of intense selective pressure.

Therefore, this trend is not specific to the Y chromosome, and there is no evidence that the reduction in the number of genes on the Y chromosome has been associated to a decrease in the fitness of humans.